# How to keep @typedef when transpiling TS to JS?

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have some TypeScript, like:

```js
/**
 * @typedef Foo
 * @type {Object}
 * @property {string} id
 */
type Foo = {
    id: string
}
/**
 * bar
 * @returns {Foo}
 */
function bar(): Foo {
    const foo:Foo = {id: 'foo'}
    return foo
}
```

that I'm transpiling (compiling?) w/Rollup. I'd like to get JS that looks like:

```js
/**
 * @typedef Foo
 * @type {Object}
 * @property {string} id
 */

/**
 * bar
 * @returns {Foo}
 */
function bar() {
    const foo = { id: 'foo' };
    return foo;
}
```

So that the `@returns{Foo}` JSDoc will be accurate in my code editor.

Rollup and [the TypeScript Playground (tsc?)](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=16&ssc=2&pln=1&pc=1#code/PQKhFgCgAIWgBALgTwA4FMAm6Bm0BiA9oVLAihtAN4DyARgFboDGiAvqXPKgE6EY8U1AM6IeASwB2AczbRxmTsCgV0BYtAC81UtD0KAXNFESZUDpFAQYcOgEMenBD3SIArj0nDqRQhdjKkDhukqzihJLQ9jwAFACURr46MHrQzBGi0DjEBknaVIbQAOTZhEX+qS7unlnE5kA) strip out Foo typedef JSDoc block.  Is there a way to keep that @typedef JSDoc block?

Comment: did you try setting `removeComments` in `tsconfig.json` to `false`?

Comment: @ACGaming, removeComments defaults to false; no that doesn't make a difference. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Type definition (interface...) will be remove when you compile ts code to js.

If you just want to keep your IDE suggestions, you can provide `"declaration: true` to your tsconfig file, tsc will compile code to js and generate  `.d.ts` file. In `d.ts` file you will have all types, variables, and function definitions.

Then your IDE will work as your expectation.

[Reference](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-files/dts-from-js.html)